# Working with .tmp file for writing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-io

I'm wondering if there is a best practice when it comes to working with .tmp file for writing data. I like to make an .tmp that will be use in the filestream and then when I close the writer, I like to rename the file. Is there a way to rename file extension?

```
    FileStream stream2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter streamWriter2 = new StreamWriter(stream2);
    streamWriter2.WriteLine(textToAdd);
    streamWriter2.Close();
    string changed = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, .txt);
    File.Move(path, changed);
```

Comment: Are you not answering your own question with `Path.ChangeExtension(...)`? Why move it?

Comment: That will just changing the string value , but what would be after that ? is it a File.WriteAllText and then what is the benefit of using the tmp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
// Build a FileInfo object for your temp destination, this gives us
// access to a handful of useful file manipulation methods
var yourFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\testfile.tmp");

// open a StreamWriter to write text to the file
using (StreamWriter sw = yourFile.CreateText())
{
    // Write your text
    sw.WriteLine("Test");
    // There's no need to call Close() when you're using usings
}

// "Rename" the file -- this is the fastest way in C#
yourFile.MoveTo(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the extension and then just add the one you want.

Comment: will that call the File.WriteAllText class?